# How to navigate to or scroll to and then highlight a particular row in flexigrid via jquery?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I have 2 [flexigrids](http://flexigrid.info/) in my page.  I would like to navigate to the particular page and highlight the corresponding row (or even focus on a particular cell) in the first grid when user select a row from the second flexigrid.  Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little crude - and I'm sure there are more elegant solutions out there - but the following works for me.

I've got a javascript function that has a TD element has a parameter (you can use the same mechanism or pass in the table row directly).

The function gets the table row, removes any selections from the parent grid and then works out the position of the row relative to its parent div before scrolling the parent div to the appropriate offset. The row in question is also 'selected' for visibility's sake.

```
function HighlightBookingShake(goTD) {
    var row = $(goTD).closest("tr");
    $(row).closest("table").find(".trSelected").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("trSelected");
    });
    $(row).addClass("trSelected");
    var goTop = $(row).offset().top;
    var parentDiv = $(row).closest(".bDiv");
    goTop = goTop - parentDiv.offset().top + parentDiv.scrollTop();
    parentDiv.scrollTop(goTop);
}
```